# How can I get the comprehensive list of all Typescript Definition Files in @types repo?

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript in my project and I have some options in terms of modules to use from the "world" -- and given everything being equal would like to have one that already has Typescript definitions -- either in the package itself or in @types (DefinetlyTyped).

The problem is that I can't see ALL the modules defined in @types -- or I can't figure out how that I know of.  Github is truncating the results of the entries to about 1400 out of 5000 files and I don't see any single definite source of what is available in the repo if I just want to search/browse for things.

One can use the Find File within GitHub but that rather presupposes you know the magic keywords you are looking for already.  And Forking the repo just to be able to search for things seems not horribly handy.

In any event, I figured this issue must have been solved but my Google skills so far haven't seen it (and strangely no direct mention on the DefinetlyType page or @types README.md).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the NPM CLI `view` command to assist you.

`npm view <package>` will attempt to display information about a package. Using it you can check for @types existence using:

`npm view @types/react`

It will either come back with information about the package, confirming its existence, or it will come back with a 404 error in the case that a package doesn't exist.

So if you have a set of packages that you need to choose between, feel free to check them for @types definitions this way.

That will help you check @types for definitions, but it won't show you whether or not a package has its types bundled in. For that check, you can use the exact same command, but on the package itself, and look for a `types` or `typings` property in the result you get back from `npm view`.

For instance, if you run `npm view redux`, you will see that the result printed has `typings: './index.d.ts'` in it, which tells you that the package comes bundled with types out of the box.

### Update

Your question got me thinking, so I built a simple CLI tool for combining the two steps I mention above. I've published the [`is-typed`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-typed) package, which you can use like:

1. Installation: `npm install -g is-typed`
2. Usage: `is-typed react redux mobx`

And it will check both the packages themselves as well as `@types` for existing type definitions.

Comment: This is pretty slick but it still presupposes you know all the available types and names ahead of time.  What if I just want to see all the @types that may work in a Koa application .. Does your is-typed allow wildcarding so "is-typed '\*react\*'" will find all types with react?  If so, that is then PERFECT!!!

Answer (score 1):

Until sometime ago, npm @types simply pulled from definitely typed on github. You can't see everything on github, but you can clone the repo and see everything locally.

Just clone https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: I actually suggested that myself in the description -- but it's quite silly to have to do this to just peruse the available @types I think.  Thanks though!

Comment: I think the idea is that type packages should have the same name as the npm packages, you shouldn't have to browse them to find them. If you installed jquery, @types/jquery either exists or not. If you want to browse all of them, going to a github central repository is not that strange. You will have the same issue trying to list all NPM packages available.

Comment: Not a fair comparison -- NPM has an extensive search operation to search for packages, etc. The point is given a possible 3 or 5 different options for a package that appears to do the "thing I want" -- I want to see if there is a @typed version of those packages ..  This is the total opposite of I KNOW which package I want and want to see if there is a \@typed package.  That is easy enough with "yarn/npn info \@types/XXXXXX" .